# Need reviews for an authentication system

Tags: c#, mvc, security, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

**AccountController Code:**

```
public class AccountController : ApplicationController
{
        public AccountController(ITokenHandler tokenStore, IUser user) : base(tokenStore, user){}

        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {

            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOn

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string email, string password)
        {
            dynamic result = user.Login(email, password);
            if (result.Authenticated)
            {
                SetToken(result.User);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = result.Message;
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LogOff

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            Response.Cookies["auth"].Value = null;
            Response.Cookies["auth"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(string Email, string Password, string ConfirmPassword)
        {

            var result = user.Register(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                SetToken(result.User);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = result.Message;
            }
            return View();
        }

        private void SetToken(dynamic user)
        {
            var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.user.SetToken(token, user);
            TokenStore.SetClientAccess(token);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ChangePassword

        [IsAuthorized]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ChangePassword

        [IsAuthorized]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ChangePasswordSuccess

        public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

**ApplicationController Code:**

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public ITokenHandler TokenStore;
    public IUser user;
    public ApplicationController(ITokenHandler tokenStore, IUser user)
    {
        this.user = user;
        TokenStore = tokenStore;
        ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser ?? new { Email = "" };

    }
    public ApplicationController()
    {
        TokenStore = new FormsAuthTokenStore();
    }
    dynamic _currentUser;
    public dynamic CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var token = TokenStore.GetToken();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                _currentUser = user.FindByToken(token);

                if (_currentUser == null)
                {
                    //force the current user to be logged out...
                    TokenStore.RemoveClientAccess();
                }
            }

            //Hip to be null...
            return _currentUser;
        }

    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentUser != null;
        }
    }
}
```

**TokenStore Code:**

```
public class FormsAuthTokenStore : ITokenHandler
{

    public void SetClientAccess(string token)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["auth"].Value = token;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["auth"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(60);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["auth"].HttpOnly = true;
    }

    public void RemoveClientAccess()
    {
        Response.Cookies["auth"].Value = null;
        Response.Cookies["auth"].Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    }

    public string GetToken()
    {
        var result = "";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["auth"] != null)
        {
            result = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["auth"].Value;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**UserModel Code:**

```
public class User : GenericRepository<User>, IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsBanned { get; set; }

    public dynamic Register(string email, string password, string confirm)
    {
        dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
        result.Success = false;
        if (email.Length >= 6 && password.Length >= 6 && password.Equals(confirm))
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic newUser = new ExpandoObject();
                newUser.Email = email;
                newUser.HashedPassword = Hash(password);
                result.User = Add(newUser);
                result.Success = true;
                result.Message = "Thanks for signing up!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Message = "This email already exists in our system";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Message = "Please check your email and password - they're invalid";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public string Hash(string userPassword)
    {
        return
            BitConverter.ToString(SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userPassword))).Replace
                ("-", "");
    }

    public void SetToken(string token, dynamic user)
    {
        Edit(new {Token = token},Convert.ToInt32(user.ID));
    }


    public dynamic Login(string email, string password)
    {
        dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
        object[] queryargs = { email, Hash(password) };
        result.UserExists = Exist("User","WHERE Email  = @0 AND HashedPassword = @1", queryargs);
        result.Authenticated = result.UserExists;

        if (!result.Authenticated)
            result.Message = "Invalid email or password";

        return result;
    }


    public dynamic FindByToken(string token)
    {
        object[] queryargs = { token };
        return Single("Token = @0", queryargs);
    }
}
```

**IsAuthorized Attribute Code:**

```
public class IsAuthorized : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _role { get; set; }
    public IsAuthorized(string role)
    {
        _role = role;
    }

    public IsAuthorized() { }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = (ApplicationController)filterContext.Controller;
        if (!controller.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Logon");
            return;
        }

        if(controller.CurrentUser.IsBanned)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<h2>Your Accound have been banned :)</h2>");
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
            return;
        }

        if (_role != null)
        {

            string userRole = controller.CurrentUser.Role;
            if (!_role.Equals(userRole))
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("Un-Authorized");
                filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Looks like you could just use the standard MVC auth module as you don't seem to be adding anything extra?

Comment: You also seem to be hashing without adding a salt, so it is actually substantially less secure than the standard one...

Comment: @Milney this was just something i wrote 2 years ago, I was just experimenting with custom authentication but yes i did not go far with it as you mentioned i added nothing extra and yes no salt was added so it's not that secure however i did benefit from that experiment and i learned a lot about authentication and authorization during my research, I also learned how to implement my own thing if it's needed at least i know how to do it and learned what went wrong with my code and what could be generally bad practice so i could avoid in the future and Thanks for contributing :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much of a web programmer, but I am comfortable with C#. So all of what I have to say is going to be based on styling. As I had posted earlier in a comment to you was to clear out any unused white spaces. It gives the impression that you don't care if there are too many extra white spaces.

The next thing that I want to talk about is your flow of thought. Although you are consistent with how you do it, it is not the most logical. This is your code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string email, string password)
    {
        dynamic result = user.Login(email, password);
        if (result.Authenticated)
        {
            SetToken(result.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = result.Message;
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

if the result is authenticated you redirect your action. But if authentication was not successful then you don't return anything??? that is how your code is phrased. Obviously next line is where you return a blank View, and you comment that if you get that far that something failed and you want to redisplay the form. You do the exact same bit of code for register. If you find exact duplicate code like that it would be better to pull it out into a method and give it a useful name. I chose this

```
    private ActionResult RedisplayForm(dynamic result)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = result.Message;
        return View();
    }
```

Now for my LogOn and my Register they are a little more to the point and easier to understand with just a cursory glace.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string email, string password)
    {
        dynamic result = user.Login(email, password);
        if (result.Authenticated)
        {
            SetToken(result.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return RedisplayForm(result);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(string Email, string Password, string ConfirmPassword)
    {
        var result = user.Register(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            SetToken(result.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return RedisplayForm(result);
    }
```

but even here I have some duplicate code. And it looks like it does the same thing as well. If the user is valid (if he's brand new or existing) then we redirect that valid user back to the homepage. ok so make a method called that

```
    private ActionResult RedirectValidUserBackHome(dynamic result)
    {
        SetToken(result.User);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Now both my methods take on a very nice and easy to read story.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string email, string password)
    {
        dynamic result = user.Login(email, password);
        if (result.Authenticated)
        {
            return RedirectValidUserBackHome(result);
        }

        return RedisplayForm(result);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(string Email, string Password, string ConfirmPassword)
    {
        var result = user.Register(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return RedirectValidUserBackHome(result);
        }

        return RedisplayForm(result);
    }
```

I don't know enough about ASP to know if i can further pull out the boolean in those, but as it sits right here it is easy enough to read this. The moral of all this is to stay consistent (which you did) but reduce as much duplication as you can without sacrificing readability. Thinking about it now I should have just passed in the required value from result instead of passing in result since it doesn't make sense in that context. So in the end I would end up with this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string email, string password)
    {
        dynamic result = user.Login(email, password);
        if (result.Authenticated)
        {
            return RedirectValidUserBackHome(result.User);
        }
        return DisplayMessageAndRedisplayForm(result.Message);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(string Email, string Password, string ConfirmPassword)
    {
        var result = user.Register(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return RedirectValidUserBackHome(result.User);
        }

        return DisplayMessageAndRedisplayForm(result.Message);
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectValidUserBackHome(dynamic validUser)
    {
        SetToken(validUser);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    private ActionResult DisplayMessageAndRedisplayForm(dynamic message)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = message;
        return View();
    }
```

WOw, this is getting to be a long post, and that is just the first file. I think this principle gives you something to think about.

Comment: Snyder thanks for your help but things doesn't run like that in the world of MVC.

For example if i do something like: 

ActionResult DisplayMessageAndRedisplayForm

return view(); Here means return a view which got the name of DisplayMessageAndRedisplayForm, that's an entirely different view, which btw does not exist.

so thanks but that won't be useful to me

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about the misdirection on that one. By all means if it was bad advice down vote

Comment: No it wasn't, am really sorry i don't mean to be rude or ungrateful but it's just not how things work in MVC, cuz things in MVC works based on naming, if i call a return view in a result action the view is actually the name of the action result.

Comment: Up vote for your point on white spaces thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: Interesting point on the naming. WPF does the same thing for dependency properties. I will stick to my guns about the logical flow of your if/else statements. I feel that your flow could be improved by removing the else statements

Comment: OK, thanks again and sorry if i sounded rude :)

Comment: Nope, never dreamt of it :) We are all in this together.